# I ask for your help in this crazy modal/dialog flow

Tags: web, dialog, modal, flow, saas

**CONTEXT**

- We are sending companies to the clients from a draft list.
- The draft list can be viewed and reviewed by **clients**, who **have to decide if they like or not these companies**
- When clients like a company, the company is saved
- **When clients don't like a company**, **we ask with a dialog why** and then we archive the company

**PROBLEM W/ THE DIALOG**

- The dialog asks: ***"Why did you pass on this company?"***
- There are two selectable reasons, once selected, the user can:

  - 1. Write more feedback about that reason and then click on CTA,
  - 2. Just click on the CTA without providing more feedback.
- **Users in general don't provide more information**, and just click the CTA (totally understandable in terms of usability)
- **The company wants that written feedback**, so we want to incentive users to write input without making that action mandatory.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I've thought of a **two-step modal**.

- **First step**: **select the reason**.
- **Second step**: a new view of the modal with a **text input asking for more info**. This is optional, and the user can directly click the CTA or write more info and then click the CTA.

In general, I don't like two-step dialogs, but adding the text input under the selected reason after being selected is failing, and I think that adding that extra step focused on the (optional) text input will get more written feedback from clients.

Answer (score 1):

I think that before you come up with a solution, you need to understand a little more about the problem(s), which you can do with user research (via a quick survey, or even by calling 5-10 clients who regularly don't fill out the feedback and just asking them.) There are several things you can try, but here are a few potential problems and solutions to get started:

**The problem: "What's in it for me?"** Most people don't give feedback unless they feel a need to do so. It's just another thing to do in their day, and if it's optional, they'll skip it.

**The solution: Provide a reason.** You could add a small line at the top of the dialog that says, "Your response will help us pick a better company for you next time." If they know that their feedback makes a difference, they'll be more likely to give it.

**The problem: "I don't have time to write an essay about this company that I don't like."** Open-ended feedback is often seen as a lengthy chore.

**The solution:** Provide a one-click multiple choice answer set with an "Other" option. Find 5-8 of the most common reasons why companies aren't being selected through your research, and list them. Let the user still have the option to write something in if their problem isn't a fit.

**The problem: Rejecting is awkward.** You stated that you're potentially sharing negative feedback with a company that was just rejected by a potential client. It's human nature to not want to hurt others' feelings, especially if there's a sense that it won't be anonymous.

**The solution:** Create psychological safety in the process. If your clients know that you're sharing their feedback, ensure them that it's anonymous and that you won't share verbatims with the companies. Broaden it into larger categories, like cost, or not enough experience.

**The problem: "It's not really their business what I think of them, just send me someone else."** When people are in a position of power over another, they don't feel that an explanation of their decisions is owed to that person or entity. If you decide not to buy a car and the dealer calls to ask why not, you're not entitled to give an answer. That's just a norm in many cultures.

**The solution:** Don't tell your clients that you're sharing the info with the companies. Make it all about optimizing their future results with you.